# My B1/B2 visa expires on Jun 7th, 2016, looking to enter US on Jun 6th 2016

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa, b1-b2-visas

My B1/B2 visa expires on Jun 7th, 2016. I'm intending to enter US on Jun 6th for a training session and return to my country (MEX) on Jun 9th. Passport is valid until 2019.

Is there a risk that CBP can deny me entrance at the Port Of Entry because to entrance date is one day before the visa expires?

Comment: You can also learn all about [What the Visa Expiration Date Means](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/visa-expiration-date.html), as linked in the duplicate answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. (Of course they could always deny you entry in general, but not for that reason.)

You can use the visa to enter on any day on, or before, the expiration date (that means you can enter on June 7th too).